# Error installing Owncloud on Linux vServer

Tags: php, mysql, owncloud

I'm trying to get [owncloud](http://owncloud.org) to run on my SUSE 11 vServer.
I managed to get the preparations done, but after I click on "Finish Setup", he gets an error saying

MDB2_Schema Error: schema parse error: Parser error: File could not be opened. - Unknown

When I looked into my php_error_log, it says the following:

```
[Fri Feb 10 09:26:14 2012] [error] [client 46.74.14.143] PHP Warning:  realpath(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 30 is not allowed to access /srv/www/vhosts/default/htdocs owned by uid 0 in /srv/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/owncloud/lib/base.php on line 129, referer: http://s402370683.online.de/owncloud/index.php
[Fri Feb 10 09:26:14 2012] [error] [client 46.74.14.143] PHP Warning:  tempnam(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 30 is not allowed to access /tmp owned by uid 0 in /srv/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/owncloud/lib/db.php on line 319, referer: http://s402370683.online.de/owncloud/index.php
[Fri Feb 10 09:26:14 2012] [error] [client 46.74.14.143] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /srv/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/owncloud/lib/db.php on line 325, referer: http://s402370683.online.de/owncloud/index.php
[Fri Feb 10 09:26:14 2012] [error] [client 46.74.14.143] PHP Warning:  fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in /srv/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/owncloud/3rdparty/XML/Parser.php on line 364, referer: http://s402370683.online.de/owncloud/index.php
[Fri Feb 10 09:26:14 2012] [error] [client 46.74.14.143] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method MDB2_Schema::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /srv/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/owncloud/3rdparty/MDB2/Schema/Parser.php on line 526, referer: http://s402370683.online.de/owncloud/index.php
[Fri Feb 10 09:26:14 2012] [error] [client 46.74.14.143] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method MDB2_Schema::errorMessage() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /srv/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/owncloud/3rdparty/MDB2/Schema.php on line 2759, referer: http://s402370683.online.de/owncloud/index.php
[Fri Feb 10 09:26:14 2012] [error] [client 46.74.14.143] PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in /srv/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/owncloud/3rdparty/MDB2/Schema/Parser.php on line 526, referer: http://s402370683.online.de/owncloud/index.php
```

Anyone suggestions? I've tried for several hours...

Answer (score 1):

You may one to take a look at the [BitNami OwnCloud installer](http://bitnami.org/stack/owncloud). It is free and can help you setup OwnCloud and all the dependencies (Disclaimer: I am a BitNami developer)